NestJS HttpException class returns status 201 when status is undefined
In this example, when the HttpException class is instantiated in this way, an exception is thrown with undefined status and becomes status 201 (I believe that in this case it is this status as it is the default status of a POST) in the endpoint response
NestJS version:
"@nestjs/common": "^8.0.4"

@ApiTags('Test')
@Controller('test')
export class TestController {
  @Post('')
  async test() {
     await this.testService.test();
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

 async test() {
    try {
      throw new BadRequestException('Test Error');
    } catch (error) {
      throw new HttpException(error, undefined);
    }
  }

}

Console logs and morgans logs:
err
{
  err: HttpException: Test Error
      at (...stack) {
      response: [Object],
      status: 400
    },
    status: undefined
  }
}
POST /test 201 6.607 ms - -

Is this behavior correct? In my opinion, it is extremely dangerous for an exception to be returned with a success status. By default, perhaps wouldn't it be better to return status 500 when it is not defined in the HttpException parameter?
I was trying to throw an exception and was surprised that an error could be returned as a success

the default status for @Post() is 201, so yes, that's expected.
But that's because you're handling the exception instead of letting nestjs to handle it. If you drop the try-catch from the controller, the response will be 500 Internal Server Error (by default)

in fact, this does not happen even if I remove the try catch from the controller. It's a valid thought, and I also think it should happen this way, but the answer even without try catch is the default POST status 201

unless you're hiding some stuff from us, there's no way the response status to be 201 if you raise an exception from the controller (ie., bubbling up to controller's caller). If this is the case, you must report it as a bug at https://github.com/nestjs/nest
